# How to extend pattern rule in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

Lets say  `$TESTOBJDIR` is a directory I freshly created to put my binary that I will be creating.

The `$TESTDIR` is a directory that contains `file1.cpp` and `file2.cpp`.

To compile `*.cpp` I need another cpp file that resides in different directory lets call it `$SRCDIR`. So by the below rule I could only do

```
$(TESTOBJDIR)% : $(TESTDIR)%.cpp
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

which gives me:

```
g++ file1.cpp -o file1 
g++ file2.cpp -o file2
```

But what I wanted was

```
g++ dir/need1.cpp file1.cpp -o file1 
g++ dir/need2.cpp file2.cpp -o file2
```

Is there a way within the pattern rule which would allow me to include the dir's .cpp file in the above way.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern I see in your goal is that `file<x>` depends on `dir/need<x>`.cpp and `file<x>.cpp`.

The following pattern rule should work.

```
(TESTOBJDIR)file% : (TESTDIR)file%.cpp dir/need%.cpp
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: When I do that the recipe now (g++ ..) is not even called :/

Comment: @pokche, I can't diagnose the problem on your computer. I tested it on mine and it works.

Comment: @R Sahu When I hard code it by doing dir/need1.cpp it works but as I place the % for pattern it stops working .. Do you have any other online resource you can point to where it has worked .. Because I searched online and cannot find any resource regarding this

Comment: @pokche, that's strange. I don't know of any online resources to try out GNU make.

Comment: FYI : By online resource I mean example code not particularly running makefile online

Comment: @pokche, unless you have more than 5 such targets, I would stop worrying about getting it work using a pattern rule. Just add all the dependencies in as many rules as you need and get to the fun stuff -- writing code and seeing it work.